# Display User ID in Mixpanel

Tags: events, analytics, tracking, web-analytics

I am using Mixpanel in a Ruby on Rails project to track real time user's events.
I am pushing the events with the user ID, and I would like to show the user ID inside the Mixpanel pages (a.i. streams page, not only the random generater user name).

Is there some way to display the user ID, or a way to filter data by user ID ?

Thank you,
Alessandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical support replied me, and told me that I can use the property called "mp_name_tag".
It works ! so now I can write the user ID in that property.

bye